# Global structure in Header files

Tags: c, header, structure, global, declaration

i have a question regarding structure in c and there declaration in header file. 
i am writing a code in which there are 3 variables which have another two variables linked with it. so i decided to declare a structure. below i'm writing a Pseudo-code

```
//----------registers.h---------
#ifndef __REG__H__
#define __REG__H__

struct ADE_reg_type
{
    unsigned int i : 4;
    unsigned int j : 4;
};

extern struct ADE_reg_type AIRMS_reg;
extern struct ADE_reg_type BIRMS_reg;
extern struct ADE_reg_type CIRMS_reg;
#endif


//-----------registers.c-------------------
#include "registers.h"

struct ADE_reg_type AIRMS_reg = {.i = 4,.j = 5};  //initializing 
struct ADE_reg_type BIRMS_reg = {.i = 3,.j = 4};  //initializing 
struct ADE_reg_type CIRMS_reg = {.i = 1,.j = 9};  //initializing 

//-----------main.c-------------------
#include "registers.h"

int main()
{
   display_numbers(AIRMS_reg);  //display_numbers(struct ADE_reg_type) has 
                              //defined in another .c file which also includes
                              // registers.h
}
```

What i'm want is that i should have a variable which i can access in any .c file. scope of variable should be global. so is it a right way to use a global structure or i'm making some mistake here ?

Comment: It's often a bad idea to use globals *at all*, but if this is really a situation where you need a global, this is indeed how you do it. The only strange thing here is the call to `display_numbers()` -- if this function shows the values of your globals, it doesn't need parameters. A *struct tag* as parameter is probably just wrong.

Comment: Oh, don't use double underscore (`__`) to start your include guards. This is reserved to the implementation. Just use `REG_H` or maybe `REG_H_`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen The shown code has changed since your (otherwise applicable) comment, hasn't it? At least I cannot see a struct tag as parameter (anymore).

Comment: @Yunnosch no I got confused, it's indeed a variable. So forget the last part of my first comment.

Comment: So, this is (at least the parts shown) working code. What exactly are your doubts? An answer simply saying "yes" doesn't look too helpful.

Comment: @FelixPalmen display_number() is a type of function which need to know two things of "AIRMS_reg". thats why i declare it as struct . secondly by using this way, i only need to send one variable to the display_number() . so is it right way to implement this situation or i should goto the like #define the two i.e. i and j and then pass them separately to the display_number() ?

Answer (score 2):

```
//----------registers.h---------
#ifndef __REG__H__
#define __REG__H__

struct ADE_reg_type
{
    unsigned int i : 4;
    unsigned int j : 4;
};


#endif


//-----------registers.c-------------------
#include "registers.h"

const struct ADE_reg_type AIRMS_reg = {.i = 4,.j = 5};  //initializing 
const struct ADE_reg_type BIRMS_reg = {.i = 3,.j = 4};  //initializing 
const struct ADE_reg_type CIRMS_reg = {.i = 1,.j = 9};  //initializing 

//-----------main.c-------------------
#include "registers.h"

extern const struct ADE_reg_type AIRMS_reg;

extern const struct ADE_reg_type BIRMS_reg;

extern const struct ADE_reg_type CIRMS_reg;

int main()
{
   display_numbers(AIRMS_reg);                               
}

//-----------------file_1.c--------------------
#include "registers.h"

extern const struct ADE_reg_type AIRMS_reg;

extern const struct ADE_reg_type BIRMS_reg;

extern const struct ADE_reg_type CIRMS_reg;

//-----------------file_2.c--------------------
#include "registers.h"

extern const struct ADE_reg_type AIRMS_reg;

extern const struct ADE_reg_type BIRMS_reg;

extern const struct ADE_reg_type CIRMS_reg;
```

Like this one you are say @Elad Hazan

Answer (score 1):

Define one global variable(of each type of course) somewhere and all the rest will be extern...
Structure has to be in header file, but never initialize or define a variable in header file - it's a bad habit.

for example:

```
//----------registers.h---------
#ifndef __REG__H__
#define __REG__H__

struct ADE_reg_type
{
    unsigned int i : 4;
    unsigned int j : 4;
};


#endif


//-----------registers.c-------------------
#include "registers.h"

struct ADE_reg_type AIRMS_reg = {.i = 4,.j = 5};  //initializing 
struct ADE_reg_type BIRMS_reg = {.i = 3,.j = 4};  //initializing 
struct ADE_reg_type CIRMS_reg = {.i = 1,.j = 9};  //initializing 

//-----------main.c-------------------
#include "registers.h"

extern struct ADE_reg_type AIRMS_reg;

extern struct ADE_reg_type BIRMS_reg;

extern struct ADE_reg_type CIRMS_reg;

int main()
{
   display_numbers(AIRMS_reg);                               
}
```

Comment: can i  declare AIRMS_reg variable to be  extern type in registers.c or i need to do this in every .c file in which i use AIRMS_reg ?

Comment: look at the example: if there is let's say AIRMS_reg variable that you want to use it in many c files, you have to declare it normally somewhere as gloabl (AIRMS_reg variable;) and on all other files as extern (AIRMS_reg variable;) another better approach is to create a getFunc() that returns a pointer to this original variable and then your code will be extremely cleaner and readable .

Comment: Added a code example - let me know if it's understood.

Comment: i'm adding a code in answer . let me correct if i'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: i can't because i have less then 15 reputation

Comment: @GauravKumar try now

Answer (score 0):

Array approach:
for example:

```
ADE_reg_type RegType_Array[3];
ADE_reg_type* ADE_reg_type(char index)
{
    return &RegType_Array[index];
}
```

Variable approach:

```
ADE_reg_type AIRMS_reg = {.i = 4,.j = 5};
ADE_reg_type* AIRMS_reg()
{
    return &AIRMS_reg
}
```